# Python sql order by

Tags: python, sql

My code:

```
sql = """
       SELECT  
       seq_no,
       step_name,
       date
       FROM
       tra..trav TR
           INNER JOIN trav..trav_step TS 
               ON TR.tr_OID = TS.tr_OI
           INNER JOIN tra..stp ST 
               ON TS.st_OID = STP.st_OID
       WHERE faci_OID = 0x16C0A 
           and TR.tr_id = '""" + str(request.GET.getlist('TravA')[0]) + "';"
```

I want to order by asc, where and how can I order by statement? Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: normally you put an `ORDER BY xyz ASC` at the end - have you tried? and i am not sure that your way of sending a python variable to your query will actually work...

Comment: You shouldn't be gluing values from your request directly into your SQL. You're inviting [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Yes added order by at the end didn't work

Comment: Add `ORDER BY` after the `WHERE` clause

Comment: why? did it have no effect or did it give you an error message?

Comment: it says invalid syntax

Comment: Can you provide the code where you added the `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY` clause goes after the `WHERE` clause, so your SQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT seq_no, 
       step_name, 
       date
  FROM TR
 INNER JOIN TS ON TR.tr_OID = TS.tr_OI
 INNER JOIN ST ON TS.st_OID = STP.st_OID
 WHERE faci_OID = '0x16C0A'
   AND TR.tr_id = (???)
 ORDER BY seq_no ASC;
```

You can find more info here:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/order_by.php

Including it in Python is a different question.

I hope I helped!